# How to hide and show two child component with *ngif but without loosing the data in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Hi is there any way to keep data on my child component while *ngIf show and hide.

I cannot use [hidden] attribute.

```
<div id="parentcomponent">
  <child1 *ngif="child1"></child1>
<child2 *ngif="child2"></child2>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
onclick(){
child1 =true;
child2=false;}

onanotherclick(){
child2=true;
child1=false
}
```

child1.html

```
<div>value need to retain on again click<div>
```

child2.html

```
<div>some value<div>
```

Comment: You can store the data in a `BehaviorSubject` and use it to restore it when the component gets rendered again.

Comment: I believe the easiest thing you can do is you can have 2 flags for each child `child1WasActivated` and `showChild1`. onclick(){
showChild1=true;
child1WasActivated = true;
showChild2=false;}. and then combine *ngIf="child1WasActivated " [hidden]="!showChild2". therefore your components will be just hidden if deactivated, but will be "lazily" activated

Answer (score 2):

Angular best practice is to create a service to store your data. The service will survive the recreation of your component, and also allow you to share data between components.

You didn't share the type of data that you want to retain, so I'm going to show an example with a single string.

First, you write the service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RetainDataService {
  public myString = 'Initial value';
}
```

Then you inject and use this service in `Child1`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'first-child',
  template: '<div>{{value}}</div>',
  styles: ['']
})
export class Child1Component {
  value: string;
  constructor(private retainer: RetainDataService ) {
    this.value = retainer.myString;
  }
}
```

When you change the value in `Child1`, be sure to update the value on the service.

You get extra credit if you use a `Subject` that emits the value and expose it as an observable instead, but this simple example also works.

As a side note, `[hidden]` is normally the wrong solution, because it leaves unused elements in the DOM and messes with your performance.

**Edit**
I should add that if your data is actually maintained in the parent component, you don't need a service. Just add `@Input()` to your property declarations, and use a binding in your parent component markup. The service strategy shown above is more flexible and more widely usable.

Comment: hi, but how I keep data of the input or drop down will which i had in my first child component, will it be get retain

Comment: That's what the service is for. In your `ngOnDestroy` you save the values to the service, and in the constructor on `ngOnInit` you load them (as shown). You can do this with any number of fields, however they are changed.